# Transpose 2d array, join second level with commas, and join first level with pipes

Tags: php, arrays, matrix, transpose, implode

I have the following two-dimensional array:

```
01 03 02 15
05 04 06 10
07 09 08 11
12 14 13 16
```

I want to convert columns to rows then reduce the matrix to a string like the following:

```
01,05,07,12|03,04,09,14|02,06,08,13|15,10,11,16
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have this array:

```
$array = array (
  array ('01','03','02','15'),
  array ('05','04','06','10'),
  array ('07','09','08','11'),
  array ('12','14','13','16')
);
```

In which case, you can do this:

```
$tmpArr = array();
foreach ($array as $sub) {
  $tmpArr[] = implode(',', $sub);
}
$result = implode('|', $tmpArr);
echo $result;
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/b4CGfUb2)

Comment: This answer is provably incorrect because it does not transpose the data. [Proof](https://3v4l.org/U0SFN)

Answer (score 3):

```
$input = array(
    array('01', '02', '03', '04'),
    array('11', '12', '13', '14'),
    array('21', '22', '23', '24'),
    array('31', '32', '33', '34'),
);
$newArray = array();
foreach($input as $rowIndex => $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        if(!$newArray[$key]) {
            $newArray[$key] = array();
        }
        $newArray[$key][$rowIndex] = $val;
    }
}
$strRows = array();
foreach($newArray as $key => $row) {
    $strRows[$key] = join(',', $row);
}
$output = join('|', $strRows);
```

Comment: This answer generates multiple undefined array key Warnings. [Proof](https://3v4l.org/s7KJe)

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant script for this "transpose and double-implode" task is to call `array_map()` with a spread operator on the input array, then join the columns with commas, the join the joined strings with pipes.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VPLhs))

```
var_export(
    implode(
        '|',
        array_map(
            fn() => implode(',', func_get_args()),
            ...$input
        )
    )
);
```

Or collect all of the column data in the function signature. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZCjVD))

```
var_export(
    implode(
        '|',
        array_map(
            fn(...$column) => implode(',', $column),
            ...$input
        )
    )
);
```

For similar questions that do not require a single string of output, but prefer an array of delimited strings, simply remove the outer implode() call.  Namely:

- [(2015) assoc arrays to two different arrays and join them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33514568/2943403)
- [(2017) How to transpose and implode subarray data within a multidimensional array to create a flat output array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43409344/2943403)
- [(2018) php concat array values into new array php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51414568/2943403)
- [(2019) Transpose multidimensional array and join values with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56670363/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Given your array as $myArray, like this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($myArray as $row) {
    $rowValue = implode(',', $row);
    $newArray[] = $rowValue;
}
$finalString = implode('|', $newArray);
```

Comment: This answer is provably incorrect because it does not transpose the data. [Proof](https://3v4l.org/caEde)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the solutions proposed so far, only one actually generates the correct output requested by the OP.

So, stealing unashamedly from salathe's neat conversion, but with a transpose to provide the correct result:

```
$input = array ( 
    array ('01','03','02','15'), 
    array ('05','04','06','10'), 
    array ('07','09','08','11'), 
    array ('12','14','13','16'), 
); 

function transpose($array) {
    array_unshift($array, null);
    return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
}

$transposed = transpose($input);

echo implode('|', array_map('implode', $transposed, array_fill(0, count($transposed), ',')));
```

Comment: While this answer DOES transpose the array data; as of PHP8 its implementation of implode() causes a Fatal error. [Proof](https://3v4l.org/FSbQN)