# How to create a string out of elements in a 2D- array in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have  2D arrays like this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 1)   [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0)   [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0
```

What I want is to print all this elements as a one string. That means, to print `"110110001000"`

I tried out something like this

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $this->smallersize; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $this->smallersize; $y++) { 

         $myarray[$x][$y] = ($dct[$x][$y] >= $avg?"1":"0");    

        }
} 
return join('',$myarray);
```

What I want is to print `"110110001000"` My problem is when I tried out the above function it gives an

> Error : "Array to string conversion" in line "return join('',$myarray);"

How to solve this?

Comment: Possibly this answers your question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757773/convert-2d-array-to-a-string-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `implode` twice as along with `array_map`

```
$array = Array(Array(1,1,0,1),Array(1,0,0,0),Array(1,0,0,0));
$result = array_map('implode',$array);
echo implode($result);//11011000100010
```

Using `foreach` as

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $v){
        echo $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me something like this. Array ( [0] => 11010010 [1] => 10000011 [2] => 10001000 [3] => 00110100 [4] => 10011000 [5] => 01101001 [6] => 10010000 [7] => 10010011 ). I want to append all of this results.

Comment: I am realy sorry, you said that  to "use implode twice as along with array_map or for" I saw it now. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @Uchiha you can use`echo implode($result);` as in `array_map` +1

Answer (score 1):

As what i have understood: you need to append all the array's element sequentially.

```
$str = "";

for ($i = 0; $i<sizeOf($array); $i++)
{
    for ($j=0; $j<sizeOf($array[$i]); $j++)
    {
        $str .= $array[$i][$j];
    }
}

echo $str;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This also works perfect. But @Uchiha has answered to the question first. So I selected  that answer as the accepted one. But I selected your answer as useful. Thanks again

Comment: no issue dear :) I am new to this so i was having some error "code is not formatted" which was not allowing me to submit, and i submitted a bit late :/ i am glad that i helped you :)