# assoc arrays to two different arrays and join them

Tags: php

I have associative arrays like this (stored in $array):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [one] => some text1
            [two] => some paragraph here1.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [one] => some text2
            [two] => some paragraph here2.        
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [one] => some text3
            [two] => some paragraph here3.        
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [one] => some text4
            [two] => some paragraph here4.        
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [one] => some text5
            [two] => some paragraph here5.        
        )

)
```

Now, I want to store the result of them like this:

> $first = 'some text1, some text2, some text3, some text4, some text5';
>
> $second = 'some paragraph here1. some paragraph here2. some paragraph here3. some paragraph here4. some paragraph here5.';

Struggling a lot I got a solution like this:

```
$first= '';
$second = '';
for($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++){
    $first .= $array[$i]['one'] . ($i == count($array) - 1 ? '': ',');
    $second .= $array[$i]['two'];
}

echo $first;
echo $second;
```

But I hope there's already a built-in php function which split assoc arrays into two different arrays.

Comment: You merely need to [implode while transposing your data](https://3v4l.org/iLo1d).  No need to call `array_column()` twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For PHP version > **5.5**. You can simply use `array_column` along with `implode` function like as

```
echo $first = implode(',',array_column($your_array,'one'));
echo $second = implode(',',array_column($your_array,'two'));
```

For lower version you can use `array_map` like as

```
echo $first = implode(',',array_map(function($v){ return $v['one'];} ,$your_array));
echo $second = implode(',',array_map(function($v){ return $v['two'];},$your_array));
```

Comment: Try this `echo $keywords = implode(',',array_map(function($v){ return $v['metakey'];} ,$results));` Missed that `, (comma)` before `$results`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ( $array as $data ) {
   $first .= $data['one'].',';
   $two .= $data['two'].',';
}

$firstdata = rtrim($first,',');
$seconddata = rtrim($two, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $arrFirst = array_column($array,'one');
 $arrSecond = array_column($array,'two');

 $first = implode(',',$arrFirst);
 $second = implode(',',$arrSecond);
```

if `array_column()` doesn't exits use this

```
if (! function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column(array $input, $columnKey, $indexKey = null) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($input as $value) {
            if ( ! isset($value[$columnKey])) {
                trigger_error("Key \"$columnKey\" does not exist in array");
                return false;
            }
            if (is_null($indexKey)) {
                $array[] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
            else {
                if ( ! isset($value[$indexKey])) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not exist in array");
                    return false;
                }
                if ( ! is_scalar($value[$indexKey])) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not contain scalar value");
                    return false;
                }
                $array[$value[$indexKey]] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

array_column() function works in > `PHP 5.5.0`

Working example:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
   array('one' => 'some text1', 'two' => 'some paragraph here1'),
   array('one' => 'some text2', 'two' => 'some paragraph here2'),
   array('one' => 'some text3', 'two' => 'some paragraph here3'),
   array('one' => 'some text4', 'two' => 'some paragraph here4'),
   );

$firstS = implode(', ', array_column($arr, 'one'));
$secondS = implode('. ', array_column($arr, 'two'));
print_r($firstS);
echo "\n\n";
print_r($secondS);
?>
```

[See it working live](https://eval.in/462677)

Explanation:

1) You need array columns.

2) Get array columns `one` and `two` in two separate arrays.

3) `impode()` these arrays to get desired output.

If your PHP version is less than `5.5.0`, you need to write a custom function for `array_column()`.

So that it will not return `Fatal Error`.

Following is the code:

```
<?php
if (! function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column(array $input, $columnKey, $indexKey = null) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($input as $value) {
            if ( ! isset($value[$columnKey])) {
                trigger_error("Key \"$columnKey\" does not exist in array");
                return false;
            }
            if (is_null($indexKey)) {
                $array[] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
            else {
                if ( ! isset($value[$indexKey])) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not exist in array");
                    return false;
                }
                if ( ! is_scalar($value[$indexKey])) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not contain scalar value");
                    return false;
                }
                $array[$value[$indexKey]] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eval.in demo links no longer work. ...any of them.