# Transpose multidimensional array and join values with commas

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, transpose, implode

How to group by comma of every value as per same key?  I need to re-orientate the array so that rows become columns and the new rows need to be joined together with commas to form strings.

My input:

```
[
    [201767.11, 514324.91, 73205.74],
    [349399.51, 647217.10, 3500.00],
    [285169.05, 522357.20, 10.00],
    [126858.21, 185190.59, 0],
]
```

Desired result:

```
Array
(

    [0] => "201767.11, 349399.51, 285169.05, 126858.21",
    [1] => "514324.91, 647217.10, 522357.20, 185190.59",
    [2] => "73205.74, 3500.00, 10.00,0"

)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43409344/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract each column incrementally and join it.  This only works with sub-arrays as shown with 0 based sequential indexes:

```
$i = 0;
while($new = array_column($array, $i)) {
    $result[] = implode(', ', $new);
    $i++;
}
```

For other non-0 based, non-sequential, non-integer, just re-index the sub-arrays before extracting and joining:

```
$array = array_map(function($v) { return array_values($v); }, $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

use can use array_map

```
$arr = array_map(null, ...$arr);
$temp = array_map(function($item){
    return implode(", ", $item);
},$arr);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 201767.11, 349399.51, 285169.05, 126858.21
    [1] => 514324.91, 647217.1, 522357.2, 185190.59
    [2] => 73205.74, 3500, 10, 0
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/B6FYa).

If you want to use one-liner

```
$temp = array_map(function ($item) {return implode(", ", $item); }, array_map(null, ...$arr));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/vL8Bu).

Notice the use of `array_map` with `null` to group the sub-arrays fetching nth index of every subarray.

`...` [splat operator](https://blog.programster.org/php-splat-operator) we use it to expose as arguments to the function.

Reference: [implode](https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), [array-map](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)