# Separate Array Values

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, foreach

I would like to know how to separate the values of an array like this below, separated by variables: https://prnt.sc/pi98a5

```
1 - 7  - Artes 1 - artes1
2 - 10 - Artes 2 - artes2
3 - 8  - Artes 3 - artes2
```

### ARRAY

```
$array = 
    [   
        ["1",           "2",            "3"         ],
        ["7",           "10",           "8"         ],
        ["Artes 1",     "Artes 2",      "Artes 3"   ],
        ["artes1",      "artes2",       "artes3"    ]
    ];
```

### FOREACH

I tried to do it myself, but it got pretty confusing for me.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $row){

    foreach ($array[$key] as $key2 => $row2){

        echo $row2; //1237108Artes 1Artes 2Artes 3artes1artes2artes3

    }

}
```

### TEST ONLINE

### - https://repl.it/@tiagocaus/EgftYyui

### - https://ideone.com/yahAkQ

Comment: What do you mean by `show` in your print screen https://prnt.sc/pi98a5 ? Where are you displaying this data?  Is it a command line or a browser or elsewhere ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73108176/2943403 might give some inspiration, but I find your [mcve] to be unclear/lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the answer provided by other users work, but i think you are not able to understand how you can put these values somewhere as a separate string.

```
$array =[

    ["1",           "2",            "3"         ],
    ["7",           "10",           "8"         ],
    ["Artes 1",     "Artes 2",      "Artes 3"   ],
    ["artes1",      "artes2",       "artes3"    ]
];

$arr = [];
$newArray=array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        $newArray[$key2][]=$value2;

    } 
}

$arr = [];
foreach($newArray as $val){
    // $arr[] = implode(' - ', $val);

    $key = $val[0];

    $arr[$key] = array(
    "title" => $val[2],
    "var" => $val[3],
    "value" => $val[1],
    );
}

print_r($arr);


// A            B        C         D
// 1    -       7   - Artes 1 - artes1
// 2    -       10  - Artes 2 - artes2
// 3    -       8   - Artes 3 - artes3
```

Comment: I need to transform that array (https://prnt.sc/pi98a5), and save it that way (https://prnt.sc/pi9hth), so I asked how to lose the values. Did you get it?

Comment: I'm not able to see your screenshots, use this [online screen shot tool] (https://snipboard.io/) and post the links of screenshot again

Comment: I need to transform that array (https://snipboard.io/yI0n1C.jpg), and save it that way (https://snipboard.io/NBMo08.jpg), so I asked how to lose the values. Did you get it?

Comment: I don't understand, second screenshot shows mixed values, one array object is different than the other array object. please show the expected result that you need in your output ?

Comment: I'm glad you understood

Comment: I just have to finish this.

Comment: I just edited my answer, please check, here is a link to the working [code](https://tehplayground.com/KiPLTJO5TVOsw8DC)

Comment: Your code is saving the array between `{}`, but should save between `[]`, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200762/discussion-between-tiago-and-omar-abbas).

Answer (score 2):

Using tabs (this depends on where the output is going to), you can just `implode()` the data, using `array_column()` to extract the column from all of the rows...

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($array[0]); $i++ ) {
    echo implode("\t-\t", array_column($array, $i)).PHP_EOL;
}
```

gives...

```
1   -   7   -   Artes 1 -   artes1
2   -   10  -   Artes 2 -   artes2
3   -   8   -   Artes 3 -   artes3
```

To just transform the data...

```
$trans = [];
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($array[0]); $i++ ) {
    $trans[] =  array_column($array, $i);
}
```

Comment: How do I put the values in separate variables so that I can retrieve them elsewhere? https://prnt.sc/pi98a5

Comment: I need to transform that array (https://prnt.sc/pi98a5), and save it that way (https://prnt.sc/pi9hth), so I asked how to lose the values. Did you get it?

Comment: Sorry - only just back from the gym.  I know you have accepted another answer, but just updated my answer for the sake of completion.

Comment: That's what it most looks like, but it's not good yet. If you can help me I change the concluding merchant.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *I change the concluding merchant*

Comment: Where there is that green option, where we mark it was completed.

Comment: His code is saving the array between `{}`, but should save between `[]`, correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = 
    array(  
        ["1",           "2",            "3"         ],
        ["7",           "10",           "8"         ],
        ["Artes 1",     "Artes 2",      "Artes 3"   ],
        ["artes1",      "artes2",       "artes3"    ]
    );

    $newArray=array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            $newArray[$key2][]=$value2;

        }
    }
    foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
             if($key2!=0)
             echo " - ";    
             echo "$value2";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: This would give exactly the same output as OP's code, how does this solve their problem?

Comment: This I already did, and returns values like this (1237108Artes 1Artes 2Artes 3artes1artes2artes3). I need to be as I informed at the beginning of the topic

Comment: @NigelRen Can you help me?

Comment: Please find the Updated answer

Comment: Print the $newArray

Comment: @MukeshYadav How do I put the values in separate variables so that I can retrieve them elsewhere? https://prnt.sc/pi98a5

Comment: I need to transform that array (https://prnt.sc/pi98a5), and save it that way (https://prnt.sc/pi9hth), so I asked how to lose the values. Did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
<table>
<?php
$array = [ ["1", "2", "3" ], ["7", "10", "8" ], ["Artes 1", "Artes 2", "Artes 3" ], ["artes1", "artes2", "artes3" ] ];
foreach ($array as $key => $row){ 
echo "<tr>";
foreach($array as $key2=> $row2){
echo "<td>".$row2[$key]."</td>";
} 
echo "</tr>";
}?>
</table>
```

**Edit**: Try to understand code

```
<table>
<?php
$array = [ ["1", "2", "3" ], ["7", "10", "8" ], ["Artes 1", "Artes 2", "Artes 3" ], ["artes1", "artes2", "artes3" ] ];
$new_arr=[];
foreach ($array as $key => $row){
$var=[];
echo "<tr>";
foreach($array as $key2=> $row2){
echo "<td>".$row2[$key]."</td>";
array_push($var,$row2[$key]);
} 
array_push($new_arr,$var);
echo "</tr>";
}
foreach($new_arr as $key => $row){
foreach($row as $key2=> $row2){
echo $row2;
}
}?>
</table>
```

This will create `$new_array` array. Try to echo and see output from same code

Comment: How do I put the values in separate variables so that I can retrieve them elsewhere? https://prnt.sc/pi98a5

Comment: Define new variables in primary loop and use `array_push()` function in secondary loop

Comment: I need to transform that array (https://prnt.sc/pi98a5), and save it that way (https://prnt.sc/pi9hth), so I asked how to lose the values. Did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

Tranpose the array, then join each line like, [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c23a60c338f05dc35f1b673ef75874b90a0fa583)

```
$array_transpose = null;
foreach($array as $k_row => $row){
    foreach($row as $k_col => $v){
        $array_transpose[$k_col][$k_row] = $v;
    }
}
foreach($array_transpose as $row){
    echo join("\t-\t",$row) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: How do I put the values in separate variables so that I can retrieve them elsewhere?  https://prnt.sc/pi98a5

Comment: I don't catch it, what value to save?

Comment: I need to transform that array (https://prnt.sc/pi98a5), and save it that way (https://prnt.sc/pi9hth), so I asked how to lose the values. Did you get it?

Comment: `$array_transpose` is the transformed array, have you check it?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to ride the way I need it https://prnt.sc/pi9hth

Comment: I need to transform that array (https://prnt.sc/pi98a5), and save it that way (https://prnt.sc/pi9hth), so I asked how to lose the values. Did you get it?